# Why is this set empty?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-set-theory

Consider for $S^2$ the map $\Phi: (0, \pi) \times (0, 2 \pi) \rightarrow  \mathbb{R^3} $ with $( \theta, \phi)) \rightarrow (\cos \phi \sin \theta, \sin \phi \sin \theta, \cos \theta) $
Why is $$ S^2 \setminus \Phi( (0, \pi) \times (0, 2 \pi))  $$ the empty set.

Comment: What is "an" empty set? Where is the integral?

Comment: By definition is $Vol_k(A)= \int_A dS(x)$. When N is an empy set, then $Vol_k(N)=0$

Comment: There is no integral in your question.

Comment: Presumably $S^2$ is the unit sphere centered at the origin. If so, then $\Phi$ definitely maps into the sphere, and the set in question is most certainly not empty. However, if you were asking about the solid Lebesgue measure of the sphere, that is zero: in general, you expect the $3$-d measure of a surface to be zero.

Comment: Is it possible that the source of this material said "null set", that you interpreted that to mean "empty set", but that the author used it to mean "set of measure zero"? (Both interpretations of "null set" exist in the literature.)

Comment: Yes that is possible. That was the source of my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read about the [spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). Briefly, consider the points such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ (aka $\mathbb{S}^2$), then define $\varphi = \arctan \frac{y}{x}, \theta = \arccos z$. This gives a bijection $\mathbb{S}^2 \rightarrow [0,\pi]\times[0,2\pi)$ with inverse $\Phi$.

Comment: How does this explain, that my set is empty?

Comment: @Leon1998 Your set isn't empty if you consider $(0,\pi)\times(0,2\pi)$ (you are missing the north pole). My answer explains that the image of $\Phi$ is exactly the sphere: the image of $\Phi$ is inside the sphere (check that $(\cos\phi \sin\theta)^2 + (\sin\phi \sin\theta)^2 + (\cos\theta)^2=1$), then if you can build an inverse it is a bijection.

Comment: Ok but how can I argue that $vol_k( S^2 \setminus \Phi( (0, \pi) \times (0, 2 \pi)))=0$

Comment: @Leon1998 if the north pole has measure $0$ (for example, if your are using the Lebesgue measure), then yes

Comment: $S^2 \setminus \Phi( (0, \pi) \times (0, 2 \pi))$ describes the north pole? Then the Lebesgue measure of a point is 0.

Comment: @Leon1998 sorry, but I was wrong: you are missing the lines $\{0\} \times[0,2\pi), \{\pi\} \times[0,2\pi)$ and $[0,\pi] \times \{0\}$. Because they are lines (one dimensional), then they have $0$ area and the integral is still $0$.